# Add unpkg to Content Security Policy (CSP)

Tags: html, cdn, content-security-policy, unpkg

How can I add specific libraries (ES modules) fetched through Unpkg to my Content Security Policy (CSP) policy - i.e. without allowing everything from Unpkg?

For example, this is how I add provide one library:

```
<script
  type="module"
  src="https://unpkg.com/web-social-share@latest/dist/websocialshare/websocialshare.esm.js"></script>
```

I tried various solution such as `https://unpkg.com/web-social-share@latest/*` or `https://unpkg.com/web-social-share@*` for my `script-src` policy but all resulted in an error:

> Refused to load the script 'https://unpkg.com/web-social-share@latest/dist/websocialshare/websocialshare.esm.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' ...

Anything that seems to work is allowing everything from Unpkg which I would like to avoid.

```
<meta
  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="default-src 'self';
    script-src 'self' https://unpkg.com/;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is available only in CSP level 3: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#external-hash. But unfortunately you'll still need to support level 2. You can however use Subresource Integrity in most browsers.

Comment: Thanks, super interesting answer!!!! Debugged a bit more, my issue is probably also the fact that I can easily allow a policy for an org `https://unpkg.com/@myorg` but can't do the same for a library without org (as the one of my question)